# Запускать поток сразу после деплоя

Tags: java, многопоточность, servlet, tomcat

Можно ли запустить поток сразу после инициализации war приложения на томкате? Имеется в виду как только приложение задеплоилось.

Пока что реализовано в виде сервлета который при get запросе запускает нужные потоки. Соответственно после деплоя нужно еще и послать запрос на сервлет что бы все заработало и потоки начали работу. Есть ли нормальный способ это сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364390/i-want-to-use-a-method-which-is-called-only-once-after-deploying-to-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно написать класс, реализующий интерфейс [`javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

Интерфейс предполагает наличие двух методов: `void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)` и `void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)`. Первый вызывается при старте приложения, второй - при завершении работы. Т.е. в вашем случае это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```java
public class ApplicationInitializer implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // здесь создаем и стартуем нужные потоки
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // здесь останавливаем потоки, Executor-ы, освобождаем ресурсы.
    }
}
```

Это еще не все. Чтобы контейнер создал экземпляр `ApplicationInitializer` и вызвал его методы, нужно добавить его в ваш `web.xml` в качестве слушателя:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>ApplicationInitializer</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает =) Весьма полезная штука